# Delete all Rows in Janus Grid

Tags: grid, janus

I'm using Janus Grid, and I want to delete all rows in a Janus grid.

```
foreach (Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXRow row in gridK.GetRows())
                    {
                       gridK.Delete();
                    }
```

Or any function to clear all Items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the DataSource to null:

```
gridK.DataSource = null;
```